# Split byte array to get the first 12 chars and the last 12 chars(Java)

Tags: java, arrays, base58

I have a byte Array which I want to Base58 encode. But I only want to encode the first 12 and the last 12 letter. So I need to convert the byte array into a String split it and convert it back into a byte array to encode it in Base58? Maybe there is a better way?

Kindly Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Arrays.copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(byte[],%20int,%20int)):

```
byte[] first12 = Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArray, 0, 11);
byte[] last12 = Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArray, byteArray.length - 13, byteArray.length - 1);
```

Comment: Hey, If I encode my original byte array with Hex.encodeHexString(originalByteArray) and then I look at Hex.encodeHexString(first12 + last12) I don't get the last and the first 12 letters. I get the first 22 and the last 24.